# How to change a date formatted number into number in SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I meet a very confusing problem when code SQL in SAS. My code is:

```
proc sql noprint;
   select VDte into :vdate 
   from test1;
quit;

proc sql;
   create table test3 as 
   select *, cdate>=&vdate. as index
   from test2;
quit;
```

I find all index=1. There should be some `index=0` and some `index=1`. When I use a number instead of macro variable `vdate`, eg. 17685(02Jun2008) instead of `&vdate.`, it works!

I also checked the VDte. Its type is numeric, format is ddmmyy10.. That is to say VDte is a number stored in SAS! But when give it to &vdate., there is some problem!!

Could someone help me to understand this situation?

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: What does `%put &vdate;` print to the SAS log?

Comment: Hi Dominic, it is 02/06/2008.

Comment: You mean textually? If VDte is a true SAS Date, it should be a number... You could use `select input(VDte, MMDDYY.)`if it's a string... (or `DDMMYY.` according to the month/day positions).

Comment: I don't think it is a text. It look like this because of format. It has been formatted as a date but I can see from the attribute the type of VDte is numeric. I also tried to use     input(VDte,ddmmyy.). There was an error "INPUT function requires a character argument.".

Comment: Hmmm what if you try `select VDte format=8. into :vdate`

Comment: It works! But I am still confusing. Why format would change the input to a macro variable?

Comment: I know it's kinda weird but proc sql's select will return formatted values, whereas in an output document or a macro variable. If you were to use the same select statement but for the creation of a table, the underlying number would be written to the table, and I am pretty sure the format would also be applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your VDte has a SAS date format, you need to "clear" it before storing its value to the macro variable:

```
proc sql;
  select VDte format=8. 
    into :vdate
    from test1;
quit;
```

Then your comparison should work fine.

Note that you could also use the date9. format for creating your macro variable and then use `cdate>="&vdate"d` in your second query.